# Code Won't Copy and Paste Specific Cells Into New Sheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code to check each row in worksheet "Report2" for the phrase "Chicago" and copy and paste any rows with "Chicago" in them into a new sheet. However, it is not working. Any help on why would be appreciated.

Code:

```
Sub BranchCount()

Dim s As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set s = Worksheets("Report 1")
LastRow = s.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Worksheets("Report 1").Select
Range("A1:J" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets.Add.Name = "Report2"
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("A1").EntireRow.Delete
Range("B1").EntireRow.Delete
Range("C1").EntireRow.Delete

Dim Z As Range
Dim Y As String

Y = W
W = "Chicago"

Sheets("Report2").Range("A1").Select

For Each Z In Range("J1:J" & LastRow)
    If Y = Z.Value Then
        Z.EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("Clean").Select
                Range("A700").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Sheets("Report2").Select
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Let me know if you can help. Thanks!

Comment: `LastRow` is from `Report 1`, you should have `W = "Chicago"` before `Y = W`, `If Y = Z.Value` only tests for **entire** cell, not partials...

Comment: Thanks findwindow. I made the edits but it's still not copying and pasting the desired rows for some reason. Any additional help is much appreciated

Comment: Uh, that was just some I noticed immediately. With those mistakes, there are bound to be more. Also, what exactly did you change `If Y = Z.Value Then` to? I doubt you used `instr`.... Edit: and you have y and z backwards....

Comment: I didn't change **If Y = Z.Value Then** to anything. and I didnt use instr. I had written a previous program following this format very similarly and it worked

Comment: You need to change `If Y = Z.Value Then`.

Comment: alright, why is that?

Comment: You have `Y=W` followed by `W="Chicago"`. Is `W` set somewhere else? As it reads now, `Y` will be an empty string.

Comment: Ah ok so I should just set Y = "Chicago" then?

Comment: Yes, also delete `W = "Chicago"` because You don't even use W in the code, unless it is a global variable defined somewhere else.

Comment: Do you want to copy only the specific cell content ? if J column matches Chicago

Comment: Yes, if the city listed in column J matches "Chicago", then I want to copy the row and paste it into a new sheet

Comment: did you try my proposal?

Answer (score 0):

no need for any helper ("Report2") sheet

you could filter the relevant part of data cells and copy selected cells directly to "Clean" sheet as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub BranchCount()

Dim s1 As Worksheet, sC As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set s1 = Worksheets("Report 1")
Set sC = Sheets("Clean")

With s1
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("A1:J" & LastRow)
        .AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:="Chicago"
        With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns("J")) > 1 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=sC.Range("A700").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End With

End Sub
```